# Allowing iframe to access libraries bundled with extension. Works sometimes, sometimes not

Tags: iframe, google-chrome-extension, permissions

In a Chrome Extension I have the following code snippet at the top of my page, enclosed in script tags. This is in a page which gets downloaded from my server, embedded in an iframe via `iframe.src = "https://example.com/extension-iframe"`

Basically it's a popup-extension which, when opened, posts an url to example.com, and when the server responds with an OK, then the popup opens an iframe with a page from the server which allows to edit the submitted url. This is to ease the development of the extension, as the coding occurs in the iframe's content instead of the extension itself, which would need to get uploaded to the chrome webstore a couple of times a day.

```
  var parameters = {};
  var tokens = document.location.search.substr(1).split("&");
  for (i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
    var values = tokens[i].split("=")
    parameters[values[0]] = values[1]
  };

  var scripts;
  var use_bundled_scripts = true; // <======= TOGGLE
  if (use_bundled_scripts) {
    scripts = [ // -- optimize for speed by bundling the libraries
      'chrome-extension://' + parameters['extension-id'] + '/libraries/moment.min.js',
      'chrome-extension://' + parameters['extension-id'] + '/libraries/angular.min.js',
      'chrome-extension://' + parameters['extension-id'] + '/libraries/angular-animate.min.js',
    ]
  }
  else {
    scripts = [ // -- else use a CDN
      'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.16.0/moment.min.js',
      'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js',
      'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular-animate.min.js',
    ]
  }
  for (i in scripts) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.async = false;
    script.src = scripts[i];
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
  }
```

This worked reliably in previous versions of Chrome (current is 56.0.2924.87) I believe version 55 included and downwards, as this problem arose recently. End of January beginning of February might be the point in time. So I believe that this is due to some change in Chrome.

As you can see, the extension loads the scripts dynamically. When I load them from cloudflare then it works everytime. But when I use the one bundled with the extension, then it works just sometimes.

It's very hard to tell under which circumstances it will work. I run multiple browsers in parallel, with their own profiles, and sometimes I get the feeling that this is when I have two or more browsers with different profiles open, but then again something tells me that this is not the case. Very hard to debug.

The problem manifests itself by the iframe page, the one trying to load those scripts, getting a status of cancelled, but no warning, nothing bad appears in the console.

[image]

The server does return the page, and `chrome://net-internals` indicates that this page gets downloaded and written into the disk cache (`URL_REQUEST` and `DISK_CACHE_ENTRY` is green)

I also do get the follwing entries (only listing the first (libraries/moment.js) of the 3)

```
25222: URL_REQUEST
chrome-extension://oadcendiggijjpegcoledekjhghejoac/libraries/moment.min.js
Start Time: 2017-02-27 15:07:24.353

t=412 [st=0] +REQUEST_ALIVE  [dt=1]
t=412 [st=0]    URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=0]
t=413 [st=1]   +URL_REQUEST_START_JOB  [dt=0]
                --> load_flags = 33024 (MAYBE_USER_GESTURE | VERIFY_EV_CERT)
                --> method = "GET"
                --> priority = "LOWEST"
                --> url = "chrome-extension://oadcendiggijjpegcoledekjhghejoac/libraries/moment.min.js"
t=413 [st=1]   -URL_REQUEST_START_JOB
                --> net_error = -20 (ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT)
t=413 [st=1]    URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=0]
t=413 [st=1] -REQUEST_ALIVE
              --> net_error = -20 (ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT)
```

So there is this `net_error = -20 (ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT)` but I have no idea why ot does get blocked only when the browser feels like doing so.

I've tried disabling all extensions (ie uBlock Origin) but that doesn't have any effect.

When it works, then it does for a couple of minutes (10 or so) after the browser started. Then again, sometimes it doesn't work at all. When I then terminate all chrome.exe an start one instance, I might get lucky and it works. This feels like a bug in chrome itself.

How can I ensure that the iframe can load bundled js files? Is there any option I can add to the manifest?

```
{

   "browser_action": {
     "default_icon": "images/sm-logo-insert-19px-amber-border.png",
     "default_title": "Add to ...",
     "default_popup": "popup.html"
   },

   "background": {
     "page": "background.html"
   },

   "options_page": "options.html",

   "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://*.example.com https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com https://ajax.googleapis.com; object-src 'self' https://*.example.com",

   "permissions": [ "tabs", "activeTab", "contextMenus", "https://*.example.com/*", "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/*", "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/*" ]
}
```

The `content_security_policy` wasn't required, I added it today to ensure that this is not causing any problems.

Comment: Could be a bug in Chrome or some Field Trial intervention enabled as of Chrome 56. Try in Chrome canary 58 which can be installed separately. Can you post a link to the extension?

Comment: Thanks, It's working in Chrome 58 (canary). The extension is not yet public, so no, ATM I can't post a link. So, how can I go about this?

Comment: You can submit a bug report on https://crbug.com but it'll probably take a long time before the cause is diagnosed. You can [bisect](https://www.chromium.org/developers/bisect-builds-py) chromium binary snapshots to find the range where the bug first appeared, then find where it disappeared. The utility will show a changelog like [this one](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+log/90784f46..9483b399?pretty=fuller) so you might be able to figure out the cause yourself.

Comment: Hmm, nope, it also occurs with Chrome Canary and an installation of Chrome Portable. It's just random, in the beginning it sometimes works, sometimes not.

Comment: Try in the older [snapshots](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Win/) (v56 is 433059 so start around 300000 for example) - download and unpack chrome-win32.zip, run `.\chrome.exe --user-data-dir=.`